# Mailto link in PDF document

Tags: pdf, mailto

I'm trying to add a mailto link in a pdf document that opens a new email with the said document as an attachment.
The user would just need to type the email in and send it... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Go to actions and then Submit form selection

```
mailto:user@domain.com?subject=This is your subject&body=The body of the message
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Acrobat's Link tool. For the Action use Open a web page. For the URL use `mailto:somebody@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You would use a Submit action, and use mailto: as protocol; there you can also specify what should be submitted (among others, the complete document).

If you can rely on your user's PDF viewer to be smart enough, you also can use the mailDoc() (Acrobat) JavaScript method.

Comment: An example of a document with mailDoc command:
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=315&t=An_ASP_NET_handler_to_create_a_personalized_PDF_form_that_it_that_will_mail_itself_to_an_e_mail_address

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me. It opens a new email with the said document as an attachment (with subject line/body copy populated):

```
this.mailDoc({cTo: "email address here", cSubject: "subject here", cMsg: "body text"});
```